# Box-Jenkins and related extrapolation methods

Tags: time-series, extrapolation

I have been reading **ARMA MODELS AND THE BOX JENKINS METHODOLOGY by S. MAKRIDAKIS AND M. HISON** 95/45/TM .

I seem to be just a little stuck on the idea of using "trends".  I think of a "trend" as a $y$ intercept and a slope.
They state in eq. 4, that
 $$T_t = a + bt$$ 
So, I get $a$ is the $y$ intercept and $b$ is the slope.
When they then say:

$$T'(t,L)= S_t + \sum_{i=1}^L \phi^i  T' _{t-L}$$

Neglecting $S$, does this mean then:

$$a'(T,L)= \sum_{i=1}^L  \phi^i  a'_{t-L}$$

and

$$b'(T,L)=\sum_{i=1}^L \phi^i  b'_{t-L}$$

?? is that all?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please consider formatting with MathJax. It will make your post much easier to read. Here is a quick guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: With a time series question you are much more likely to get an answer on the stats stack exchange.